# Converting BIO* to PKCS7* in C++ using OpenSSL library

Tags: c++, c, openssl, pkcs#7

I've got a problem regarding BIO* to PKCS7* conversion. I want to call PKCS7_decrypt() function to decrypt a cipher text. Before that, I have this section of code:

```
in = BIO_new_mem_buf(chEnc, iLength);
if (!in) {
    fprintf(stderr, "\nError in BIO_new_mem_buf in verifyEC. STDERR: ");
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    return 0;
}

p7 = d2i_PKCS7_bio(in, NULL);
if (!p7) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error in d2i_PKCS7_bio.\n");
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    return 0;
}
```

d2i_PKCS7_bio() always fails and returns this error message:

140172957116064:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1319:
140172957116064:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:381:Type=PKCS7

Any idea how to fix it? Is it the problem due to encoding? or is it a conversion problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to a wrong input format:
d2i_PKCS7_bio expect a binary der PKCS7.

On the other hand, if your input is in a pem format you should call PEM_read_bio_PKCS7 instead.